# Mirror not working for me

Tags: mirror

I've been mirroring objects with the scale "-1" on one axis for ages and now suddenly it doesn't work. The eyebrow works fine but the eyelash doesn't work at all and mirrors weirdly. Please help me if you know the solution to this problem.

[image]

Steps I have taken to fix this:
Applied the scale, rotation, and location, double checked the world's axis and object's origin.

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? Only keep the useful elements

Comment: Yes sure!
Here it is

https://drive.google.com/file/d/10fGEhIhmqHEPDHYvlfMSm1Fobfe7dsn7/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Set the *Transform Orientations* to *Local*, switch to the *Move* tool, switch the *Orientation* to *Default* and you'll see that the origin orientation is not what you think it is. To correct that you could for example align the eyelash origin with the head orientation. Also, are you sure that you want to animate such a high-poly head?

[image]

To align the eyelash origin with the head origin, select the head and create a custom orientation:

[image]

Enable the *Affect Only Origins* option:

[image]

Select the eyelash and *Object > Transform > Align to Transform Orientation*:

[image]

Disable *Affect Only Origins*:

[image]

Also don't forget to switch back to *Global* or *Local Transform Orientations*:

[image]

Do the <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>-1</kbd> operation on the eyelash, it should work.

Comment: Thank you for this, but, I tried this and it still not working the way I wanted it to be :( the head is not actually in a symetry with the world's axis so when I modeled the eyelash on world's axis, I had to mirror it using the axis of the head, it works fine with the eyebrow and eyes stuff, only the eyelash bugs out for some unknown reason which I had no single clue why.

Comment: PS: I've tried unsubdividing the head down but my uv unwrap gets messed up, also, Im just gonna do some light animation with it so it didnt bother me that much hahahah

Comment: Are you sure that you've correctly realigned the eyelash origin? See my edit...